# How does Google Play determine location? How do I trick it to think I'm in US? VPN and location spoofer don't work

Tags: google-play-store, geolocation, in-app-purchase

I just want to buy in-game content from Play Store and I can't redeem the code (with the "need more info" error). It's a US code, my phone has US settings, I cleared all Play data, made an account set in the US, and I use VPN and FakeGps which work on Google Maps, but YouTube and Play still know I'm not in the US right now, and I can't find any more info on what else it uses to tell where I am.

Comment: I guess Google have upgraded their VPN detection mechanisms, I think they base it on an ISPs level now.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat is saying nonsense. When you are using a VPN, there is no way for the receiver to know your ISP, since the way to get your ISP is with your IP address which is precisely what a VPN is spoofing. It can only check that you're in a VPN, again from your IP address, and block you.

Comment: If you have bought something then Google assigns you a fixed country which can only be changed once a year. Once this country is assigned to your account it doesn't matter in which country you are located based on your IP. Check play store settings for the currently assigned country.

Comment: @adamency I don't understand the rant, but this is exactly what I was trying to say, they know the VPNs IP addresses and block them that essentially means there is a set of IPs (US) from the known ISPs that are allowed. BTW learn to be polite in you conversations. Also do not put too much trust in VPNs, they've got to many limitations.

Comment: @adamency Despite what many VPN providers advertise VPNs are useless (at best ineffective) at: 1. Achieving anonymity. 2. Preventing Google or Facebook from collecting your private data. 3. Hiding your mobile phone location (GPS). I wonder what makes you think Google can't detect your location when using a VPN, perhaps as you have bluntly tried to explain above a VPN can be at least useful Encrypting your data so your ISP or mobile network provider cannot monitor or log your online activity. (credits: ivpn.net)

Answer (score 0):

It most likely knows this from your SIM card and phone number which is not a US one simply.